# Can I use SQL Server replication components using Developer version?

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication

Can I use SQL Server replication components using the free Developer SQL Server version?

When I choose options in SSMS Replication | Configure Distribution, I get message:

### Configure Distribution Wizard

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio is unable to access replication components because replication is not installed on this instance of SQL Server. For information about installing replication, see the topic Installing Replication in SQL Server Books Online.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Replication components are not installed on this server. Run SQL Server Setup again and select the option to install replication. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 21028)

OK

I will try to re-review install steps.

There does not seem to be any option I can find in the "SQL Server Installation Center" options for Replication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Replication is available in SQL Server Developer Edition. You just forgot to install the Replication components. Note that contrary to Alex's reply, Replication is not installed as a part of the main SQL Server installation. You need to select **SQL Server Replication** on the **Feature Selection** page of the installer. This is covered in [Install SQL Server Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-replication).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your replies Brandon and Alex. 
Both answers contain valuable information !
I will mark Brandon's answer as correct although Alex's answer is a correct step in the process also.

SQL Server 2017 same or similar to SQL Server 2016.

[image: SQL Server Installation Center option for add features]

[image: SQL Server 2017 Feature selection]

It seems I have to pick a new Instance at the "Instance Configuration" step?

Maybe not .. (as per Alex's answer)

I should have paid more attention back at the "Installation Type" question! I should have paid attention to Alex's answer also.

i.e. I want to pick the "Add features to an existing instance of SQL Server 2017" radio button here.

This worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible, according to Microsoft documentation.

Replication is installed as part of the main SQL Server installation, when you opening the installer.

Run installer and select "New SQL Server stand-alone installation **or add features to an existing installation**".

A new window will open, that will check for existing instances.
Select existing instance:
[image]